# PHP MVC (Manual) with Datatable

Tags: php, model-view-controller, datatable

I am new with mvc and I am not using any PHP framework because I need to create my project using my OWN mvc.

The problem now is, I am stuck how to pass database records into the Datatable.

All my previous projects are not using mvc which I can copy-paste directly.

URL:

```
http://localhost/project/public/user/showAll
```

View:

```
<table id="datatable_users" class="display nowrap row-border hover order-column" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 13px; margin-top: 20px; display: block">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="30%" class="text-left">StaffNo</th>
        <th width="30%" class="text-left">StaffName</th>
        <th width="30%" class="text-center">EmailAddress</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th width="30%" class="text-left">StaffNo</th>
        <th width="30%" class="text-left">StaffName</th>
        <th width="30%" class="text-center">EmailAddress</th>
    </tr>
 </tfoot>
```

Controller:

```
public function showAll() {
    //to model
    $data['data'] = $this->model('User')->getAllUsers(); //from model's method

    //troubleshoot
    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($data);
    //echo '</pre>';
    //die();

    //Yes, this return data

    $this->view('user/showAll', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function getAllUsers() {
    $output = array();

    $query = $this->pdo->prepare('select * from tims_user_dtl');
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($result) {
        foreach ($result as $column) {
            $output[] = array('StaffNo' => $column['staff_no'], 'StaffName' => $column['staff_name'], 'EmailAddress' => $column['email_address']);
        }
    }

    $results = array(
        "sEcho" => 1,
        "iTotalRecords" => count($output),
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($output),
        "aaData" => $output
    );

    return json_encode($results); //pass to datatable
}
```

Datatable setting:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#datatable_users').DataTable({
            "bFilter": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bLengthChange": true, //show dropdown box
            "bAutoWidth": true, //Enable or disable automatic column width calculation
            "autoWidth": true,
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 30, 50, 100, -1], [10, 20, 30, 50, 100, "All"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 10, //jQuery Datatables pagination setting
            "scrollX": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            "searching": true, //searching part
            ajax: {
                "url": "http://localhost/ims/public/user/showAll",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                {data: 'StaffNo'}
                , {data: 'StaffName'}
                , {data: 'EmailAddress'}
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    'targets': 0, //index
                    'className': 'dt-body-left',
                    'searchable': true,
                    'data': 'StaffNo'
                }
                , {
                    'targets': 1, //index
                    'className': 'dt-body-left',
                    'searchable': true,
                    'data': 'StaffName'
                }
                , {
                    'targets': 2, //index
                    'className': 'dt-body-left',
                    'searchable': true,
                    'data': 'EmailAddress'
                }

            ],
            "order": [[1, 'asc']]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please guide me, thanx

Comment: `need to create my project using my OWN mvc` Why? Also, where's the `view` method definition?

Comment: Maybe you should think about an own ajax endpoint, which returns the json data for the datatable and not using the same url for html and ajax (just a guess - as we can't know how your mvc framework actually works..)

Comment: *"Please guide me"* - **How?** It's *your* MVC. How are we to know what the rest is and how it works. You've been given an answer below, see that. Far as I'm concerned, this question is unclear and won't help anyone else but yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatable ajax option expects JSON yet the url you passed returns html (I guess that's what '$this->view()' does).
Keep that controller action to generate and render your view and add a new route where you'll fetch data, encode it in JSON and return it.